# Android RelativeLayout: How to put a view above another view, without necessarily touching?

Tags: android, view, alignment, android-relativelayout

I am displaying a ListView that can have any number of rows. I want the ListView to wrap the content. I also want some text to be at the bottom of the screen, regardless of the size of the list. Like so:

[image: What I want to happen]

My attempt at making this happen is below, but when the content is large, it causes it to look like the bottom left image.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/blue">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fine_print"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
        android:layout_below:"@+id/table"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      />
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/table" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_box">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And adding

```
android:layout_above="@id/fine_print"
```

to @id/table makes it look like the bottom right image.

[image: What ends up happening]

How can I make it do what I want?

Comment: In conjunction with a fixed-size list, this may be useful http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/smart-headers-and-footers-in-scrollviews/

Comment: Did you read the article? I still think it might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems a bit weird, but here's how I got it working. Since the text at the bottom is of size "8dip", and takes up either 1 or 2 lines depending on screen orientation, I put a padding of "16dip" below the list.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/blue">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/details_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="16dip">
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/table" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/white_box">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fine_print"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Still open to suggestions on making this cleaner, though.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a cleaner solution to this?

Comment: @Kalina + yugidroid solution works. use this xml and add android:layout_below:"@+id/table" will work for you

Answer (score 5):

Answering the topic: `view.bringToFront();`

You can also try in xml this: `android:translationZ="10dp"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can resolve your issue by simply adding to your `TextView` something like

`android:layout_below:"@+id/table"`

Let me know if ot works.

Comment: No, that also causes the text on bottom to be pushed off screen, like the bottom left image.

Comment: Kalina + @yugidroid solution works. use this xml and add android:layout_below:"@+id/table" will work for you